# why could member names in a union be the same as typedef names in C?

Tags: c, typedef

I found this definition below in the "compiler_defs.h" that comes with SiLabs IDE for 8-bit MCU applications. I have done a little search work, it seems to be relevant to name spaces and identifier visibility issue. There are 5 name spaces used in C (ref: [Name Spaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bx5ywe6y.aspx)):

1. Statement labels
2. Structure, union, and enumeration tags
3. Members of structures or unions
4. Ordinary identifiers
5. Typedef names

and an example is:

```
struct student {
    char student[20];
    int class; 
    int id; 
    } student;
```

I am OK with the above example, but I am still confused about the code below, so **why could the typedef names be the same as the member names in a union definition**?  Would you please shed some light on this? Thanks.

Code excerpt from "compiler_defs.h":

```
typedef unsigned char U8;
typedef unsigned int U16;
typedef unsigned long U32;

typedef signed char S8;
typedef signed int S16;
typedef signed long S32;

typedef union UU16
{
   U16 U16; // [typedef name] [member variable name]
   S16 S16;
   U8 U8[2];
   S8 S8[2];
} UU16;

typedef union UU32
{
   U32 U32;
   S32 S32;
   UU16 UU16[2];
   U16 U16[2];
   S16 S16[2];
   U8 U8[4];
   S8 S8[4];
} UU32;
```

Create my own main.c and include compiler_defs.h:

```
U16 U16; // this line in main.c cause compiler error: redefinition in VS2015, WHY?
```

Comment: Can you explain why points 3 and 5 being different namespaces does not answer your question?

Comment: I answered your original question, then your edit changed your question. If you've got a new question ask a new question. In any case it's not possible to tell why you're seeing a "redefinition" error from VS without more context than just that line (for example, the actual error message, the lines that the error identifies, the lines immediate surrounding your declaration in case there's a syntax error on a previous line, any relevant other code, etc.).

Comment: I would ask Silbas why their library is so weird and why it doesn't use standard C types from `stdint.h`. I would suspect you get the same reply as I get when I ask them why they still use 8051: "This crap isn't crap at all, it's actually awesome! Because - reasons."

Comment: Note: please try to avoid this kind of thing when you write code.  It causes test and maintenance engineers to take pills, swallow Glocks or jump from high buildings :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make the point clear. If "U16 U16; // [typedef name] [member variable name]" is valid in the union definiton, why is "U16 U16;" defined  as a global variable in main.c invalid?  I've checked C99,  it seems only 4 name spaces exist, and typedef names share the same name space with that for #4 Ordinary identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Well you sort of answered your own question:

> 1. Statement labels
> 2. Structure, union, and enumeration tags
> 3. Members of structures or unions
> 4. Ordinary identifiers
> 5. Typedef names

These are separate namespaces, i.e. a name in one won't clash with the same name in another one. In your case:

```
U16 U16; // [typedef name] [member variable name]
```

The first `U16` is in namespace #5 in your list. The second is in namespace #3. Separate namespaces, so the names can be the same without conflict.

Comment: but if put this "U16 U16; // [typedef name] [member variable name]" in the file scope as a global variable definition, compiler will report error.